# MYSQL and PHP re-Numbering elements

Tags: php

The code I have works except for that I am trying to renumber all the items on table "example2" starting from 1. So for example I have 3 elements entered on the table and which contain ("url","number"). number is used to keep track of the elements, so if number 2 is removed i need the remaining two elements to adjust where the first is still 1 and the third becomes 2. Here's what I have:

```
<?php
 $field1_name = $_POST['Number'];
 $size = 0;
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM example2 WHERE number='$field1_name'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example2");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 $size = $row['COUNT(*)'];
 $l = 1; while ($l <= $size) { $temp = "${"example2_$l"}"; 
 mysql_query("UPDATE example2                                              
 SET number = '$temp' WHERE number = $l"); mysql_query($query)or 
 die(mysql_error());$temp++; $l++;};

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'table.html';
  </script>
```

Comment: The approach would greatly depend on the number of rows of data.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `UPDATE example2 SET number = number - 1 WHERE number > :cutoff` ? Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: As a programmer I really don't get the move to mysqli. It makes no sense to add extra code for simple functions. I'm all for global variables but totally against the change to ooe

Comment: @Adsy2010: mysqli still has a procedural interface as well as an object oriented one. And there are other benefits over old mysql_ functions, such as prepared statements.

Comment: the question is: how do i renumber all the elements once one is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is a little confusing - you call `mysql_query` twice, the second time with an undefined variable `$query` (I assume as a result of debugging efforts).

A simpler solution might be to subtract one from all the elements greater than the deleted one:

```
<?php

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or die(mysql_error());

 $field1_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Number']);

 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM example2 WHERE number='$field1_name'") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_query("UPDATE example2 SET number = number - 1 WHERE number > '$field1_name'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

 mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I've also added some escaping for your input since you were vulnerable to an SQL injection as it was. You may want to consider using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as a more robust solution.